# Removing values from table using a function or spx

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table and that table stores the values of the users as:

```
ID     USERID      Items        
1       54           1,2,3,4,5,6
2       55           1,2,5,6,7,8
3       56           1,2,3,4,5,6
4       57           1,2,3,4,5,6
5       58           1,2,3,4,5,6
6       59           1,2,3,4,5,6
7       54           1,2,3,4,5,6
```

so i am trying to remove the values `1,2,7` from items column for every `userId`

i can write a code inphp which can run and loop over and find a item in the column list and remove but that is what is expected, better to get that into doing as sql

i can do basic functions of sql but my knowledge with advanced is not much, how can i remove these items

thinking of as a function where i can use `@declare = 'items as comma seperated to be removed'` and write **some kind of loop which if it finds will remove it**

Well Indeed, i forgot to mention, There is another table called users which has users details in it based upon `Userid, firstname,lastName` so apparently it will **loop over the users table andginside that it will loop over** this to make corrections

Comment: Why you implemented the table like that? If you made a M-N relation everything would be simpler. Have you some requirements about implementing your table that way?

Comment: this is a old table which was created long back and it is being used in the system for a while now, so probably it cannot be changed now, but all we can do is modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a more robust solution (for not only 1,2 and 7 but any wished sequences) use this solution:

First, Create a `split` function. Just copy/paste this (credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)) code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split (@InputString varchar(8000),
@Delimiter varchar(50))

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
  Item varchar(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
  IF @Delimiter = ' '
  BEGIN
    SET @Delimiter = ','
    SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
  END

  IF (@Delimiter IS NULL
    OR @Delimiter = '')
    SET @Delimiter = ','

  DECLARE @Item varchar(8000)
  DECLARE @ItemList varchar(8000)
  DECLARE @DelimIndex int

  SET @ItemList = @InputString
  SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
  WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
  BEGIN
    SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
    INSERT INTO @Items
      VALUES (@Item)

    -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
    SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex + 1, LEN(@ItemList) - @DelimIndex)
    SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
  END -- End WHILE

  IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
  BEGIN
    SET @Item = @ItemList
    INSERT INTO @Items
      VALUES (@Item)
  END

  -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO @Items
      VALUES (@InputString)

  RETURN

END -- End Function
GO
```

**Edit:** As per @Sean Lange comment, please consider a better performance split function as described [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Second, here is the code:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
  ID int,
  UserID int,
  Items varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @table (ID, UserID, Items)
  VALUES (1, 54, '1,2,3,4,5,6'), (2, 55, '1,2,5,6,7,8'), (3, 56, '1,2,3,4,5,6'),
  (4, 57, '1,2,3,4,5,6'), (5, 58, '1,2,3,4,5,6'), (6, 59, '1,2,3,4,5,6'), (7, 54, '1,2,3,4,5,6');

DECLARE @toBeRemoved TABLE (
  num varchar(16)
);
INSERT INTO @toBeRemoved (num)
  VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('7');

DECLARE @forUserIds TABLE (
  userId int
);
INSERT INTO @forUserIds (userId)
  VALUES (54), (55), (56), (57), (58);

SELECT
  ID,
  UserID,
  Items,
  LEFT([Sub].[NewItems], LEN([Sub].[NewItems]) - 1) AS 'NewItems'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
  ST2.*,
  (SELECT
    ST1.Item + ',' AS [text()]
  FROM (SELECT
    *
  FROM @table a
  CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Items, ',')
  WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT
    num
  FROM @toBeRemoved)) ST1
  WHERE ST1.ID = ST2.ID
  ORDER BY ST1.ID
  FOR xml PATH (''))
  [NewItems],
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY id) AS RowNo
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM @table a
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Items, ',')
WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT
  num
FROM @toBeRemoved)) ST2) [Sub]
WHERE RowNo = 1
AND UserID IN (SELECT
  userId
FROM @forUserIds);
```

Notice the `@toBeRemoved` table and `@forUserIds` tables. These are exactly the tables you can change as you wish and dynamically modify. The result is dependent on these tables. The `@table` is just for testing purposes. Replace it by your actual table.

**Edit2:** Here is the sql `update` statement instead of `select`. I changed the `@table` to `YourTable`. Just use your table name instead.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Items = LEFT([Sub].[NewItems], LEN([Sub].[NewItems]) - 1)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
  ST2.*,
  (SELECT
    ST1.Item + ',' AS [text()]
  FROM (SELECT
    *
  FROM YourTable a
  CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Items, ',')
  WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT
    num
  FROM @toBeRemoved)) ST1
  WHERE ST1.ID = ST2.ID
  ORDER BY ST1.ID
  FOR xml PATH (''))
  [NewItems],
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY id) AS RowNo
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM YourTable a
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Items, ',')
WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT
  num
FROM @toBeRemoved)) ST2) [Sub]
WHERE [Sub].RowNo = 1
AND [Sub].UserID IN (SELECT
  userId
FROM @forUserIds)
AND [Sub].ID = YourTable.ID;

SELECT
  *
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: That splitter is really awful for performance. There is no need to use loops for splitting delimited strings. And multi-statement table valued functions are horrible on their own. Here are several better options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Nonetheless a plus 1 from me as the rest of this works as expected

Comment: very cool, but i am confused a bit, we i need to create a complete code of @table and inserts and this portion `DECLARE @table TABLE ID int,UserID int,Items varchar(50_);
INSERT INTO @table (ID, UserID, Items)VALUES (1, 54, '1,2,3,4,5,6'), (2, 55, '1,2,5,6,7,8'), (3, 56, '1,2,3,4,5,6'),(4, 57, '1,2,3,4,5,6'), (5, 58, '1,2,3,4,5,6'), (6, 59, '1,2,3,4,5,6'), (7, 54, '1,2,3,4,5,6');DECLARE @toBeRemoved TABLE (num varchar(16));
INSERT INTO @toBeRemoved (num)VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('7');
DECLARE @forUserIds TABLE (userId int);INSERT INTO @forUserIds (userId)VALUES (54), (55), (56), (57), (58);~

Comment: because my table has more columns too so is that inserts necessary

Comment: if i have more values how do i send them to the toberemoved, is this an spx, or function or what?

Comment: anyways, i manged to make it work, now i want to delete the original column called as items and rename the new column newlist as items and reflect that in table permanatly

Comment: @Jack Sorry for late comment, yes, the `@table` is here just for demo purposes (as I needed some test data to test the function). If you need to remove the old items values just perform sql `update` from select. Should be easy. In terms of `@toBeRemoved` table - the same as `@table`. You can replace it with your actual users table. Again it was just for demo data.

Comment: i managed to do the changes i required, now the only action item which u told me to do an update is bit difficult for me because i am basically a front end guy so much with db, can you update your answer to include my last comment thanks

Comment: update somehow created a mess, now it goes in a loop and never comes back.

Comment: just 50 rows, no more one table has 4000 rows which is the users table and other table called as yourtable has 40

Comment: @Jack That should be fine. The `update` itself works fine for me. Does it throw any error message or it just runs and never ends?

Comment: it just runs and never ends, i think select was good with the exception we can write update at the bottom after select

Comment: @Jack I can't reproduce this. Works well on my machine. Perhaps give it some time. The update statement is OK. The last `SELECT
  *
FROM YourTable` doesn't have to be there..I added it just to see the result after the update finishes but it's not necessary there.

Comment: i changed this to select mode for test purpose and it started giving me Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. error

Comment: @Jack Do you still get the exception? System.OutOfMemoryException sounds odd. Perhaps we could try a different split function with a better performance.

Comment: yes it does throw that, what it last night is, it actually took off the entire database and i had to restart the sql server to bring it back, some kind of uncommitted thread or something, not sure what bu it went off yesterday completely

Comment: @Jack Is there any possibility you could run the sql on smaller number of records? e.g. not 4000 but lets say 50.

Comment: i will try to do that, let me backupmy database

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as:

```
update t
    set items = stuff(stuff(new_items, len(new_items) - 1, 1, ''), 1, 1, '') 
    from (select t.*,
                 replace(replace(replace(',1,', ',' + items + ',', ''
                                        ), ',2,', ''
                                ), ',7,', ''
                        ) as new_items
          from t
         ) t;
```

`new_items` is the list of items with 1, 2, and 7 removed, but still starting and ending with a comma.  The `stuff()` function is used to remove the leading and trailing comma.

Comment: will `stuff()` will work if it does not have a leading or trailing comma, and what if i have more than 3 values, i have to use more replace, correct

Comment: @Jack . . . This is putting leading and trailing commas on the list and then removing them.  If you have more items, you would need another nested replace for each item.  The above example shows the code for two.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work...

```
declare @CommaSeparatedValues varchar = '1,'
update TableName
set Items = REPLACE(Items, @CommaSeparatedValues, '')
```

Comment: but how we wrap in a function and also it needs to be userid dependent, i mean i have another table which  has list of users like userid,firstname,lastname and indeed that is required too for this to make it happen

Comment: You didn't specify a length for your varchar and the default for a variable is 1. And what about values like 11,

Comment: yes, u are correct, basically `varchar` is 255, but that `varchar` can also have a value of `training_id, training,training_summary`

Comment: Typo issue.. it should be varchar(AnyLength). For other tables or filters you can use Joins and WHERE clause.